# Reading a range of cells in an Excel doc gives me an error

Tags: c#, excel

I can read single cells but i can't manage to read rows or columns.
With this code i get to read a single cell:

```
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\bla\blas\users.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);                
            Console.WriteLine(xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "A1").Value.ToString());
```

But when i try to set a range like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(xlWorkSheet.get_Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1], xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 3]).Value.ToString());
```

I get this error: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'get_Range'.

Comment: tried `xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "C3")` ?

Comment: When i try this, i get the following: System.Object[,]

Comment: Hi! Can you show how you define the variable xlWorkSheet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\bla\blas\users.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);                

Range range1 = worksheet1.Cells[1, 1];
Range range2 = worksheet1.Cells[3, 3];

Range range = worksheet1.get_Range(range1, range2);

object[,] valArray = range.Value2 as object[,];
int xCount = valArray.GetLength(0);
int yCount = valArray.GetLength(1);

for (int i = 1; i <= xCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= yCount; j++)
    {
        object currentValue = valArray[i, j];
        if (currentValue != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(currentValue.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```